# Return back when clicking an item on a SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

How can I close open fragment and return to main activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
public SlidingMenu sm;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Main layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);


    // SlidingMenu
     sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    sm.setBehindOffset(120);
    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);

    // Left menu
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new LeftMenuFragment()).commit();

    // Right menu
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_second);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new RightMenuFragment()).commit();         

}



public class LeftMenuFragment extends Fragment{
 ImageView img;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_left_menu, container,
            false);
    this.inflater = inflater;

 img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
 img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //RETURN TO MAIN ACTIVITY
        }
    });

 }
 return view;
}
```

Is it possible to create vertical sliding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to close the sliding menu just do

```
if(sm.isMenuShowing()){
    sm.toggle();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create vertical sliding?

Comment: the sliding menu library does not support that